# Does Regrow Crops in caves ever have to be replanted?

Tags: rune-factory

After experience my first storm i lost almost 60% of my crop of Corn (11/27 survived) however when i went into Carmite Cave for some grinding i found there was no change to the farming plots unlike my farm.

Since it seems that crops in caves are unaffected by storms i used [this FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/930701-rune-factory-a-fantasy-harvest-moon/faqs/51707) i looked up which Regrow produce would net me more money out of Spring and Fall (as i only have access to Carmite and Toros Caves) since i'm lazy and don't want to replant every time i harvest, as a means to have a continue source of safe income.

Now given each cave is always a particular season, at the end of the month do you still have to replant regrowing produce? (as you would outside because of the change to the season)